# sub-menu in mini-menu that can shown just from Admin

Tags: socialengine

Can anybody help me that how to create new sub-menu that shown just from admin . any one can help me .
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify socialengine's engine4_core_menuitems table. For the correct menuitem you can create a submenu by filling "submenu" param of the needed menuitem. In "submenu" you should state menu name, of course. SocialEngine will do other things for you automatically, you only need to find proper admin menu and menu item to call submenu.

Comment: I'm create the item , but just I need to be shown from admins, see this http://test.3eesho.com/ and look to the mini-menue .
there are ARTICLE MANAGER show for all , I need to be seen from ADMIN.

Comment: @EhabA.Qad'oumi Don't sure I understood you right, but:
1) if you need this menu item to be shown only on admin panel pages, you should add this menu item in the same way as menu items related to core_admin_main created.
2) if you need this menu item to be shown in mini-menu, you can add this menu item using standard menu editor, but then add User_Plugin_Menus to the 'plugins' column of this menu item. Then you should edit User Menus plugin to set the rule for this particular menu item (by analogy with core_mini_admin menu item).

Comment: how I can set the rule for the particular menu item ?

Comment: I set this attributes .....
name : core_menu_AM ;;;;
module : core_mini_admin ;;;;
label : Article manager ;;;;
plugin : User_Plugin_Menus ;;;;
menu  : core_main

Comment: @EhabA.Qad'oumi module name is wrong. Leave just 'core'. As you listed 'User_Plugin_Menus' to process this menuitem, you need to customize its code to catch this particular menuitem and show it only for admins (by analogy with core_mini_admin menu item), as I said before. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've added module to core , but when I make plugin as User_Plugin_Menus the website is not show "white page"